# Не запускается копия программы после macdeployqt

Tags: c++, qt, macos, mac

Программа по событию от пользователя запускает свою копию через скрипт с параметрами для выполнения определённого задания. Скрипт имеет SETUID флаг и запускает копию программы от рута.

До вызова macdeployqt это работает. После macdeployqt при попытке вызвать копию программы получаю ошибку.

=====================================================

> [13:48:12]  [D] "objc[53451]: Class NotificationReceiver is
>   implemented in both
>   /Users/administrator/Projects/win3-build-Release/my_app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
>   and
>   /Users/administrator/Devel/Qt/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>       QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fef58c00080) is not the object's thread (0x7fef58d091a0).
>       Cannot move to target thread (0x7fef58c00080)
>
> On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the
>   same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt
>   binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of
>   binaries are being loaded. This application failed to start because it
>   could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa".
>
> Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

=====================================================

Дочерний процесс вызываю так (в данном случае вызывается скрипт)

```
QProcess p;
p.start(command, params);
if (waitWithEventProcessing(p, timeout))
   ....
```

Скрипт вызывает приложение так:

```
if [ "$1" == 'makeСonnection' ] ; then
    '../../MacOs/MyApp.AC' -makeСonnection "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"   
fi
```

В чём может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: я 100 лет macdeploy не использовал, но Ваша ошибка очевидна. Не во всех загружаемых бинарниках прописан путь внутрь bundle. В тексте ошибки Вам предельно ясно говорится, как найти виновника. Дальше по цепочки развёртывайте и разбирайтесь, какой из бинарников не прописан и почему.

Comment: Но ведь первая копия программы запускается нормально. Проблема только, когда она пытается запустить себя же через скрипт. До того, как этот финт ушами был реализован, нормально собирался pkg и разворачивался и работал на других машинах.  

И сейчас, если собрать pkg, развернуть на другой машине, где qt не установлен, программа запускается, но запустить себя же через скрипт не может.

Comment: Нужно смотреть, что где и как загружается. Проводить исследование. Это самостоятельная работа, другие тут Вам не помогут.

Answer (score 1):

Решение частично найдено. Если скрипт вызывает программу по полному пути, то такой ошибки не возникает.

```
if [ "$1" == 'makeСonnection' ] ; then
    /Users/administrator/Projects/MyApp-Release/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp' -makeСonnection "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"   
fi
```

Comment: Теперь задача получить в скрипте абсолютный путь к файлу. К сожалению и тут возникли вопросы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431718/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82