# Не удаётся нормально передать путь к файлу из программы в скрипт

Tags: c++, qt, macos, mac

Скрипт вызывается через QProcess

```
QProcess p;
p.start(command, params);
```

Один из параметров скрипта - путь к приложению

```
params.append(qApp.applocationFilePath());
```

Скрипт выводить полученные параметры

```
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

вместо нормального пути получаю строку, где слэши заменены на X:

> XUsersXadministratorXProjectsXMyApp-ReleaseXMyApp.appXContentsXMacOSXMyApp

пробовал поместить в кавычки - не помогает, добавляются ещё два X по краям строки

```
params.append("\"" + qApp.applocationFilePath() + "\"");
```

Цель - получить полный путь к файлу. Может есть другие варианты?

Comment: Решил проблему "вручную" - при формировании параметров заменил слеши на спецстроки и в скрипте восстановил, работает

Answer (score 1):

Используйте setNativeArguments() :

```
QString nativeArguments="\"+QDir::toNativeSeparators(qApp.applocationFilePath())+\"" ;
p.setNativeArguments(nativeArguments);
p.start(command);
```